# Laravel 5.4 сохраняет в БД неверные данные

Tags: php, laravel, миграция, one-to-many

Есть 2 таблицы, Пользователи и голоса пользователей(в которой хранятся айди пользователей, за которых пользователь уже голосовал)

Миграция Users.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('access_token');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('photo_url');
            $table->integer('rating');
            $table->integer('vote');
            $table->boolean('can_play');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Миграция User_vote

```
Schema::create('user_votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')
                ->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('CASCADE')
                ->onUpdate('RESTRICT');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Класс моделей.

User.

```
class User extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['access_token', 'user_id', 'photo_url', 'rating', 'vote', 'can_play'];

    public function votes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserVote');
    }
}
```

UserVote

```
class UserVote extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id'];
}
```

В итоге когда я пытаюсь добавить к текущему пользователю новую запись в таблице голоса, он записывает в БД не ожидаемый результат.

```
$user->votes()->save(UserVote::create(['user_id' => 5]));

id | user_id  |
 N |    1     |
```

Предполагается, что `user_id` должен быть '5', а он добавляет '1' (`P.S. '1' - это id $user` )

Comment: не понял, а почему такая конструкция: `$user->votes()->save(UserVote::create(['user_id' => 5]))`? почему не просто `UserVote::create(['user_id' => 5])`? чисто из любопытства, а то понять не могу, или всей сути не понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую ответить, хотя мне немного не понятна логика в этом выражении

```
$user->votes()->save(UserVote::create(['user_id' => 5]))
```

сначала выполняется `UserVote::create(['user_id' => 5])`, он сохраняет новую запись и возвращает массив созданного элемента и там будет поле `user_id` и оно = `1` (вы сами написали), затем вы сохраняете запись этим выражением `$user->votes()->save`, точнее аппдейтите, так как в массиве передается и `id`.

В итоге ваша первая запись перезаписывается.